# Proxy configuration for GIT and NPM in Windows10

Tags: node.js, github, npm

How to configure the corporate proxy url for GIT & NPM package in Windows 10. There is no .gitconfig or .npmrc file created in Users folder.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm config set proxy "your proxy"

npm config set https-proxy "your proxy"
```

To show setup

```
npm config list
```